# passing query results through li results

Tags: php

I have a query which creates a list of image-links, I want to pass to pass a variable through the url of these image links. However, because there are multiple results, when I try to pass it, I get the query multiplied by however many results there are.

For example if $filter = "sub 1, sub 2" and that returns three images, then passed_filter = "sub1, sub2, sub1, sub2, sub1, sub2"

So what I'm trying to make it do is passed_filter = "sub1, sub2".

$filter is passed from a multiselect dropdown. And passed_filter, is the results from $filter getting sent back to the results page.

Any ideas on how I could change the code below to do what I want?

The php page:

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Currently Displaying: Custom Selection</h2>";

    include ("connect.php");

    $filter = $_GET["filter"];
    $filterIn = $filter;

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM edt_images
                                WHERE cat1 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR cat2 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR cat3 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR cat4 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR cat5 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR cat6 IN ($filterIn)
                                ORDER BY vote_item_id")                         
            or die(mysql_error());



        echo "<div id='results_container'>";
        echo "<ul id='items'>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo "<li><a href='subpage.php?passed_filter=".$filter."&id=".$row['id']."' border='0'>
                         <img src='files/300x200/thumb2_".$row['item_name'].".".$row['file_extension']."' border='0' class='filtered_images'/>
                         </a>
                            <br />
                                <strong>
                                    ".$row['file_tag_line']." 
                                </strong>
                      </li>"; 
        }

        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</div>";
?>
```

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to post.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I don't see why you are storing `cat1, cat2, ...` as columns. You should consider normalizing your structure. It will make your life easier.

Comment: I made it that way for the search function. I wanted people to be able to filter using multiple categories. I realize I could still do this if it was normalized, its just a lot of rework at this point.

Comment: Your search function would work better if your table was normalized.

Comment: alright, I'll have a look at doing that after. For now how about we have a look at the problem at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Stop using `mysql_` functions

### 2) Normalize

```
CREATE TABLE edit_images_category (
  id tinyint,
  category varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (id, category));

INSERT INTO edit_image_category (id, category)
SELECT id, cat1 AS cat FROM edit_images
UNION ALL
SELECT id, cat2 AS cat FROM edit_images
UNION ALL
SELECT id, cat3 AS cat FROM edit_images
UNION ALL
SELECT id, cat4 AS cat FROM edit_images
UNION ALL
SELECT id, cat5 AS cat FROM edit_images
UNION ALL
SELECT id, cat6 AS cat FROM edit_images
```

### 3) Do a search

```
SELECT * FROM edit_images_category WHERE cat IN ($filterIn)
```

### [See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a12fc/1)

Comment: Yeah got it, need to normalize, not the problem I'm having, move past it. variable is being repeated in the while loop. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Owen The way I see it, this is the *root* problem. If you had a normalized schema you most likely wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wasn't trying to be rude, was just looking for help. I will start pluging away at that.

Comment: @Owen Don't think you were. I'm just trying to help you from the bigger picture.